# How to achieve this using Joomla?

Tags: joomla1.5

I want to build a website using Joomla. My target is something like this [http://www.training.my](http://www.training.my/)/. My question is how to achieve the functionality like that website?(The course pricing table, the download menu)

If you know some extension that is useful for this, please recommend for me.

Thank you.

Comment: You see an online chat there in that website. Ask them :)

Comment: they using custom cms. i planning to use only joomla.

Answer (score 0):

You need DT register. It's commercial but well worth the price.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/calendars-a-events/events/events-registration/2037